# hovertext to label (is there a way to make the hovertext stay displayed forever and not only when u hover your mouse over the chart)

Tags: php, graph, phpmyadmin, fusioncharts

This is my php script where i am querying a database to get data and plot the data using fusion chart

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM chronology_chart"; 
if( $result = mysqli_query ($connect,$query)){
$stack = array( );  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $stack[] = $row["Tapeout-Date"];
    $variable .= "<category name = '$row[Date]' hoverText = '$row[Event]'/>";
}
$variable .= "</categories>";
$variable .= "<dataset seriesname='' color= '99cc00' renderAs='line' showAreaBorder='0' areaBorderThickness='2' areaBorderColor='' isTrendZone='1'>";

$arrlength = count($stack);
#echo $arrlength;
#print_r($stack);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++){
    $variable .= "<set value = '$stack[$x]'/>";
}   
$variable .= "</dataset>";
$variable .= "</graph>";
```

}

now this will make the date in $row[Event] to appear as hovertext when i move the mouse over graph line.
is there a way to make that hovertext value to be displayed always .!!!?
please help

Comment: i am not able to put up a picture of the graph.. could you pls take a look at this url and let me know

https://lh4.ggpht.com/Z0P9VW-UnXklhB1JW5FnVY1ih_4XSUld2T1bA7dRRx7QOcxngtPU1swAIa52QoagqppOSas=s154

Answer (score 0):

`hoverText` is equivalent to tooltip text and that should not stay always visible.

You should try using `displayValue` instead (if using v3.x)

Comment: displayValue is only displaying the value that is in $row['date'] and it also is displayed only when i move the cursor on it..

is there any other way to display a label for each of the values that are plotted.?

Comment: "displayed only when i move the cursor on it" -- you sure about that? Seems that in my end, this changes the text shown next to the anchors of the line.